# How to make this search query in django?

Tags: python, django

my search query works fine when i fill the book and chapter in my searchfield. but when i only fill in the book i get an error. Can somebody help me?

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=genesis
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
def get_queryset(self): 
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    book, chapter = query.split()

    object_list = Verse.objects.filter(
        Q(book__icontains=book) & Q(
            chapter__exact=chapter))

    return object_list
```

Comment: You mention that you get an error. Please include it in your question.

Comment: i included the error

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, since then there is only one word, and hence `query.split()` will return a singleton list.

```
def get_queryset(self): 
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = Verse.objects.all()
    if query:
        query = query.split()
        object_list = object_list.filter(book__icontains=query[0])
        if len(query) > 1:
            object_list = object_list.filter(chapter=query[1])
    return object_list
```

I'm however not convinced that splitting by a space is a good idea here. If the book name contains spaces, then `.split()` will thus split the title, and you will take the second word as `chapter`. You might want to split on an identifier like a colon (`:`).

Comment: You are right. When the book has a space it gives an error. You have another solution maybe?

Comment: @IlseVanDommelen: as said, it might be better to use a different separator, like a colon. You can then `query = query.split(':')`.